# no answers from a non-redirectional HttpURLConnection request in Java

Tags: java, url, redirect, httprequest, httpurlconnection

here's a minimal example of what I try to do :

```
public static String fetch () {

    // get a connection to the website
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL("http://example.com?param=ok").openConnection());

    // configure the connection
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);


    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    // send the request
    DataOutputStream ostream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    ostream.flush();
    ostream.close();


    // receives the response
    InputStream istream = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
    }
    reader.close();

    return response.toString();
}
```

To reach "*http://example.com*", the server sends a redirection first and **HttpURLConnection** automatically uses this redirection, then displays the response of this final dead-end page.
I want to get the byte-code of this intermediary response.
To do so, I tried to use the method **setInstanceFollowRedirects** and set to **false** (see the code). It seems to work since there is no output anymore but this is why I post here because there is no output anymore fuuuu

Does one have a fricking clue of why nothing is displayed when I try to output the `return response.toString();` ?

Comment: This May help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)
BTW I removed the ?param=OK from your example and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite clear why you don't get a response string. You disabled to automatically follow redirects. So you will probably get a response which only consists of headers, no body. Your response string is collecting the bytes of the body and since there is no body in a response only saying "go to another location" your string is empty.

You should do [`connection.getResponseCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode()) and read the `Location` header to know where to go next. Then you can create another request with this new location and you will get the "real" response.

I don't know what exactly you mean with "the byte code of intermediary response". I suppose you're interested in the header values. You can get all headers with [`connection.getHeaderFields()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderFields()). You iterate this map and collect all interesting header values for further processing.

Comment: sometimes I can get self-amazed of how far stupid I can reach, this was so obvious, thanks mister.

Comment: You're welcome. Isn't this daily life that we feel stupid? :-)